# Лицензирование деятельности при работе с ЭЦП

Tags: криптография, лицензирование, юридические-аспекты

Необходимо ли лицензирование деятельности у ФСБ при разработке ПО с применением программно-аппаратных криптографических средств (в моей случае это опыт с eToken ГОСТ и JaCarta ГОСТ компании Aladdin R.D.) для целей аутентификации и формирования юридически значимой квалифицированной подписи на документы, если данное ПО подразумевается как коммерческий продукт для внешнего использования клиентами и третьей стороной?

Согласно [п.3 постановления РФ от 16 апреля 2012 г. № 313](http://base.consultant.ru/cons/cgi/online.cgi?req=doc;base=LAW;n=128739;fld=134;dst=1000000001,0;rnd=0.8929619961418211) не могу однозначно понять.

Налицо встраивание уже лицензированного решения, вроде не разработка, но встраивание, и возможно распространение. Сами криптоустройства и плагин для связи токена и системы не распространяю. Само решение и без данной криптозащиты спокойно работает, но код взаимодействия остается.

Ответ на вопрос так же искал на форумах аладдина и криптопро, хабре и тостере, а так же направил вопрос в службу поддержки указанного решения.

Так или иначе может кто-то сталкивался с данным вопросом при разработке?

Comment: Не парся, КГБ тебя само найдет, если нужно. ;-)

Comment: @cpp_user Может одного меня и не жалко ;-) , но если продавать от лица компании, то страдания растут асимптотически.
Простой подписи с использованием смс уже не хватает, так что нужно все же изучить вопрос.

Comment: Это проблемы юристов, директоров и лица компании значит но никак не программистов.

Comment: @cpp_user Страдает компания - страдают и сотрудники. Я же как программист хотел бы знать, что рассматриваемое мной решение не потребует излишних затрат, а друзей юристов у меня нет. Если и у вас их нет, то предлагаю разойтись пить чай :)

Comment: А денег на юристов тоже нет? Ну тогда согласен что вам делать нечего.

Comment: @cpp_user Не понимаю провокаций с вашей стороны. Контекст компании - это для сравнения. Штрафы у юр. лиц просто выше. А вы всегда когда программируете для себя и сталкиваетесь с гос.тематикой нанимаете юриста?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31414/discussion-between-ice2burn-and-cpp-user).

Comment: Ice2burn: Вы не поверите но и когда болею иду к врачу. ;-)

Comment: @cpp_user ну есть же какие-то юристы для бедноты

Answer (score 6):

Вот что удалось самостоятельно выяснить:

Если использовать криптоустройства только для целей двухфакторной аутентификации, то лицензия не нужна, т.к. шифрование не осуществляется. (впрочем, здесь есть сомнения и все зависит от используемого протокола)

Если формирование ЭЦП, обслуживание и др. используется для личных нужд или внутренних нужд компании, то под постановление не попадаем.

Лицензия ФСБ требуется при встраивании криптографических средств (даже сертифицированных) в ПО которое будет предоставляться как товар/услуга для других лиц.

Соответственно при заказной разработке или для предоставления другим лицам как услуги лицензия фсб все же нужна.

---

В итоге остается 6 возможностей:

1. Самостоятельное получение лицензии ФСБ со всеми вытекающими последствиями;
2. Само приложение поставлять без криптозащиты. Ее подключать в виде отдельного модуля с помощью пользователя и/или посредника. При этом модуль в таком случае должен разрабатываться и распространяться отдельно посредником, имеющим лицензию. Поставлять модуль необходимо отдельно от основного приложения. Другими словами: использовать услуги другой стороны;
3. Использовать простую подпись без криптографии, например усиленную смс-подтверждением. При этом нужно формировать соглашение между сторонами обмена о том, что такая подпись признается юридически значимой. А в суде факт формирования такой подписи осуществляется проверкой логов сервера и др. согласно условиям соглашения.
4. Использовать средства СКЗИ встроенные в ОС. (под закон не попадает)
5. Осуществлять подпись не на территории РФ. (Электронные подписи, созданные в соответствии с нормами права иностранного государства и международными стандартами признаются юридически значимыми согласно законодательству РФ)
6. Не использовать криптографию и ЭЦП вовсе.

---

Отсутствие данной лицензии после первой возмездной/безвозмездной передачи другой стороне является нарушением [статьи 171 "Незаконное предпринимательство" уголовного кодекса РФ](http://www.consultant.ru/cons/document/cons_doc_LAW_10699/cc12ef68af6f5296cb8a9dad10ca87865d02f12f/) а так же, [КоАП РФ, Статья 13.13. Незаконная деятельность в области защиты информации](https://www.consultant.ru/document/cons_doc_LAW_34661/39ec2d46bb9a543aad7de74b6fef2d96b56aef6c/) и сулит серьезный штраф и возможно конфискацию всех СКЗИ.